Простейший инженерный калькулятор на основе алгоритма сортировочной станции
Пишу тривиальный инженерный калькулятор на основе алгоритма сортировочной станции. Всё в принципе работает.
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <string.h>

#include <ctype.h>

#include <math.h>

#include <locale.h>

#include <wchar.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 100

typedef struct {

    float data[MAX_SIZE]; // Данные стека

    int top;// Вершина

} Stack;

void initialize(Stack* stack) {

    stack->top = NULL;

}

int isEmpty(Stack* stack) {

    return (stack->top == NULL);

}

void push(Stack* stack, float ch) {

    if (stack->top == MAX_SIZE - 1) {

        printf("Stack is overflowed\n");

        return;

    }

    stack->data[++(stack->top)] = ch;

}

float pop(Stack* stack) {

    if (isEmpty(stack)) {

        printf("Stack is empty\n");

        return '\0';

    }

    return stack->data[(stack->top)--];

}

int isOperator(char ch) {

    return (ch == '+' || ch == '-' || ch == '*' || ch == '/' || ch == '^' || ch == '!' || ch == 'q' || ch == 's' || ch == 'c');

}

int getPriority(char ch) {

    if (ch == '+' || ch == '-')

        return 1;

    else if (ch == '*' || ch == '/')

        return 2;

    else if (ch == '^' || ch == '!' || ch == 'q' || ch == 's' || ch == 'c')

        return 3;

    else

        return 0;

}

void infixToPostfix(char* infix, char* postfix) {

    Stack stack;

    initialize(&stack);
    int i, j;

    int k = 0;

    char ch;

    char tmp[10];

    char xs[123] = { 0 };

    char xs1[123][10];

    for (i = 0, j = 0; infix[i] != '\0'; i++) {

        ch = infix[i];

        if ((int)ch >= 97 && (int)ch <= 122 && ch != 'q' && ch != 's' && ch != 'c') {

            if (xs[ch] > 0) {
                while (isdigit(xs1[ch][k])) {
                    postfix[j++] = xs1[ch][k++];
                }

                k = 0;

                postfix[j++] = ' ';
            }

            else {

                printf("Enter the value of the symbol %c: ", ch);

                fgets(tmp, 10,stdin);

                while (isdigit(tmp[k])) {
                    postfix[j++] = tmp[k++];


                }

                k = 0;
                
                postfix[j++] = ' ';


                xs[ch]++;

                while (isdigit(tmp[k])) {
                    xs1[(int)ch][k++] = tmp[k++];
                }

                k = 0;
            
            }

        }

        if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\t')

            continue;

        if (isdigit(ch)) {

            while (isdigit(infix[i])) {

                postfix[j++] = infix[i++];

            }

            postfix[j++] = ' ';

            i--;

        }

        else if (isOperator(ch)) {

            while (!isEmpty(&stack) && getPriority(stack.data[stack.top]) >= getPriority(ch)) {

                postfix[j++] = pop(&stack);

                postfix[j++] = ' ';

            }

            push(&stack, ch);

        }

        else if (ch == '(') {

            push(&stack, ch);

        }

        else if (ch == ')') {

            while (!isEmpty(&stack) && stack.data[stack.top] != '(') {

                postfix[j++] = pop(&stack);

                postfix[j++] = ' ';

            }

            if (!isEmpty(&stack) && stack.data[stack.top] == '(') {

                pop(&stack);

            }

            else {

                printf("Error: wrong expression\n");

                return;

            }

        }

    }

    while (!isEmpty(&stack)) {

        if (stack.data[stack.top] == '(') {

            printf("Error: wrong expression\n");

            return;

        }

        postfix[j++] = pop(&stack);

        postfix[j++] = ' ';

    }

    postfix[j] = '\0';

}

float evaluatePostfix(char* postfix) {

    Stack stack;

    initialize(&stack);

    int i;

    float result, operand1, operand2;

    char num[10];

    int numIndex = 0;

    char ch;

    for (i = 0; postfix[i] != '\0'; i++) {

        ch = postfix[i];

        if (isdigit(ch)) {

            while (isdigit(postfix[i])) {

                num[numIndex++] = postfix[i++];

            }

            num[numIndex] = '\0';

            numIndex = 0;

            push(&stack, atoi(num));

        }

        else if (ch == ' ') {

            continue;

        }

        else if (isOperator(ch)) {

            if (ch == '!' || ch == 'q' || ch == 's' || ch == 'c') {

                operand1 = pop(&stack);

                switch (ch) {

                case '!':

                    result = 1;

                    for (int j = 1; j <= operand1; j++) {

                        result *= j;

                    }

                    break;

                case 'q':

                    result = sqrt(operand1);

                    break;

                case 's':

                    result = sin(operand1);

                    break;

                case 'c':

                    result = cos(operand1);

                    break;

                default:

                    printf("Error: unacceptable operator\n");

                    return 0;

                }

            }

            else {

                operand2 = pop(&stack);

                operand1 = pop(&stack);

                switch (ch) {

                case '+':

                    result = operand1 + operand2;

                    break;

                case '-':

                    result = operand1 - operand2;

                    break;

                case '*':

                    result = operand1 * operand2;

                    break;

                case '/':

                    result = operand1 / operand2;

                    break;

                case '^':

                    result = pow(operand1, operand2);

                    break;

                default:

                    printf("Error: unacceptable operator\n");

                    return 0;

                }

            }

            push(&stack, result);

        }

        else {

            printf("Error: wrong symbol in postfix\n");

            return 0;

        }

    }

    result = pop(&stack);

    if (!isEmpty(&stack)) {

        printf("Error: wrong expression\n");

        return 0;

    }

    return result;

}

int main() {

    char infix[MAX_SIZE];

    char postfix[MAX_SIZE];

    printf("q - sqrt, s - sinus, c - cosinus\n",251);

    printf("Enter the expression: ");

    fgets(infix, sizeof(infix), stdin);

    infix[strlen(infix) - 1] = '\0';

    infixToPostfix(infix, postfix);

    //printf("Postfix: %s\n", postfix);

    float result = evaluatePostfix(postfix);

    printf("Result: %.2f\n", result);

    return 0;

}





Только для примера a*a(где a - переменная, которую задаёт пользователь) visual studio выдаёт ошибку вот в этом куске.
if (xs[ch] > 0) {
    while (isdigit(xs1[ch][k])) {
        postfix[j++] = xs1[ch][k++];
    }

    k = 0;

    postfix[j++] = ' ';
}

xs[] - это массив, содержащий повторы символов. xs1[] - двумерный массив из символов и их значений в строковом формате. При дебаге выяснил, что при первоначальном считывании символа всё хорошо. При вторичном считывании берутся пустые значения вообще из другой части xs1[]. Хотя переменная k, указывающая на начало строки символа ch, после всех выполненных операций с числом обнуляется, дабы потом при последующем обращении начать пробегать по строке с самого начала для вторичного считывания числа.
